# Removing n number of elements from a list

Tags: haskell

One of my modules this year is Haskell programming. I'm having trouble expressing complexity in such a simple manner, especially coming from other languages such as C#.

Part of the familiarisation process involves us implementing a drop' function which removes n number of elements from a list.

**Write a function drop’ :: Int -> [a] -> [a], where drop’ n xs returns xs with its first n elements removed.**

So far, what I have come up with is this.

```
drop' :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
drop' x [] = []
drop' x (y : ys) = if x == 0 then ys else drop' (x-1) ys
```

I know I need to recursively call drop' on the tail of the list to effectively remove an element but I don't know how to keep a count of how many elements I have removed so I can ensure I remove n elements.

I know the above doesn't give me the result I was expecting as it removes 1 more than I expect, but interestingly this works:

```
drop' :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
drop' x [] = []
drop' x (y : ys) = if x == 1 then ys else drop' (x-1) ys
```

And I cannot deduce why! Any help with the logic of this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Count from 5 to 0, there will be six numbers. So, in the first case you are removing 6 numbers whereas in the second you are removing exactly 5 (counting from 5 to 1). Apart from that, there is a typo in the first one I guess, `If x == 0 then ys`, perhaps?

Comment: The condition ensures that elements are only removed if x does not equate to 0, so in the first case it should be: 5 = 1 removed, 4 = 2 removed, 3 = 3 removed, 2 = 4 removed, 1 = 5 removed. But this isn't the case!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to keep track of how many elements you *have* removed so far, only how many you *have yet* to remove, and that's the value of the `x` parameter.  So you already have that part.

The problem with your first version of the function is that when `x` is 0 you return `ys`, but that's just the tail of the list, since you've already removed the first element via pattern-matching in the argument list.  You'd need to use `if x == 0 then (y:ys)` to return the entire input list.

Alternatively, you can use the the `tail` function in the recursive case instead of pattern-matching:

```
drop' x ys = if x == 0 then ys else drop' (x-1) (tail ys)
```

And you can put the zero case on a separate line instead of using `if`, so the whole definition is:

```
drop' :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
drop' _ [] = []
drop' 0 ys = ys
drop' x ys = drop' (x-1) (tail ys)
```

Comment: This explained it really well thank you! For some reason I thought returning the tail of the list when x = 0 was in fact the whole list when it wasn't.

Comment: Your `drop'` will fail if given list is empty and first parameter is greater then zero. It's not behavior of real `drop`.

Comment: @Mark, I'd intended for those two lines to be read as a replacement for the single line from the question, not a complete definition of the function, so they're implicitly preceded by the type declaration and the empty-list case.  But I can see how that may not be clear, so I've edited the answer to provide the full definition with all four lines.

Answer (score 4):

In your code here:

```
drop' x (y : ys) = If x == 0 then ys else drop' (x-1) ys
```

This is the source of your off-by-one error: if `x` is 0, you want to return the whole list unchanged (`y:ys`), not just the tail (`ys`).  Equivalently, you could check for 1 instead of 0, and then return `ys`.

It would be more idiomatic to use pattern-matching instead of `if`, and you should use the `_` don't-care variable for values that you don't use:

```
drop' :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
drop' _ [] = []            -- dropping any number of items from [] is still empty
drop' 0 lst = lst          -- dropping nothing returns the list unchanged
drop' n (_:xs) = drop' (n-1) xs  -- otherwise remove head and recurse on the tail
```

Comment: I've edited the xs error. This makes complete sense, but to familiarise ourself with Haskell we aren't allowed to use the drop function provided in Haskell!

Comment: @Bradley - I didn't mean to; the `drop` with no apostrophe was a typo.  Check edited answer.

Comment: In your answer you used underscore keywords instead of values, what is the effect of this and why is it any different to using x for example. EDIT do you use _ because we're removing it from the list thus we don't care about it's value?

Comment: @MarkReed, an underscore is a placeholder that means you're not giving a name to whatever value is in that position; it's used in cases where the value is irrelevant.  When the list is empty you don't care how many elements you've been asked to drop, and when using pattern-matching to extract just the tail of the list, you don't care what its head is.  There's no real harm in assigning names to those values anyway, but using the underscore makes it clearer to the reader that they're not used, and can help you avoid referring to them by mistake (e.g. with a typo).

Comment: If you enable extra warnings with `-W`, GHC will warn you if you don't use a name, unless it starts with an underscore.

Comment: That was Bradley,not me, @Wyzard. But yes, _ just means "I'm not using this value".  It's a clear signal to both the interpreter/compiler and humans reading the code that the value doesn't matter for that case.

Answer (score 0):

The following approach may prove instructive as well, even that no recursion is used. Consider this comprehension,

```
drop' :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
drop' n xs = [ v | (_,v)  <- filter (\(x,_) -> x > n) $ zip [1..] xs ]
```

Qualities of interest in this example,

- we (lazily) zip list `xs` with an index value starting from `1` up to the number of elements in `xs`;
- `filter` includes a lambda function that extracts the first element in the *zipped* tuple, and compares the value against the number of elements to drop off;
- for each filtered tuple, we extract the second element, a value from the original list.

Then for instance

```
drop' 4 ['a'..'t']
"efghijklmnopqrst"
```